# A RegEx that matches correct comma placement in a string

Tags: regex, parsing, numbers

I am wanting to check user input to where it check whether a string has correct comma placement, and if the number is valid in human eyes too.

These are numbers that are allowed:

- `1,000`
- `100`
- `1`
- `1,000,000,000,000,000`

Here are numbers that are not allowed:

- `1e+5`
- `1e5`
- `1,00`
- `-105`
- `100.50`
- `100,00,00,0,000000`

I've tried to come up with my own RegEx but this is very complicated for even me to understand. This is my RegEx (`^[0-9]{0,3}(,[0-9]*)?$`) but it is very broken at the moment.

Is anyone able to help?

Comment: Use `^\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*$`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Could you submit that as an answer so I can mark as answered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
^\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/p0dXvB/1)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `\d{1,3}` - 1, 2  or 3 digits
- `(?:,\d{3})*` - zero or more consecutive occurrences of

  - `,` - a comma
  - `\d{3}`  - 3 digits
- `$` - end of string.